# Query JSON object within a list (Postgres 11)

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, postgresql-11

I have a "contact_info" column that stores jsonb, which look like this:

```
[ {"phoneNumber":"123-4567", "emailAddress":"email@address.com"} ]
```

I'm trying to retrieve all the rows where phone number equals "123-4567".

How can I do this in a one-line query? I can return the whole column with `SELECT contact_info FROM db_name.db_table;` but haven't had success pulling the individual objects and querying the phone numbers inside.

I've been looking at [this question][1] but it is slightly different than my situation (list of json objects vs json object containing a list), and I can't figure out how to apply the solution to my version of the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/functions-json.html) function as

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM t
 CROSS JOIN JSONB_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(contact_info) AS js(elm)
 WHERE js.elm ->> 'phoneNumber' = '123-4567'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=7802c3daddd8bccc5f4f821778c4121b)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks a lot! I wasn't initially sure how this worked and having the demo helped me figure it out.

Answer (score 1):

If all of your arrays have just one element, this is straight-forward:

```
select t.*, t.contact_info -> 0 ->> 'emailAddress' as email_address
from db_table t
where t.contact_info -> 0 ->> 'phoneNumber' = '123-4567'
```

Else, can use `jsonb_array_elements()` and a lateral join to unnest the array, then filter:

```
select t.*, x.obj ->> 'emailAddress' as email_address
from db_table t
cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements(t.contact_info) x(obj)
where x.obj ->> 'phoneNumber' = '123-4567'
```

Note that this returns multiple rows if more than one object in a given array matches on the phone number. If you want to avoid that, you can use a subquery:

```
select t.*, x.obj ->> 'emailAddress' as email_address
from db_table t
where exists (
    select 1
    from jsonb_array_elements(t.contact_info) x(obj)
    where x.obj ->> 'phoneNumber' = '123-4567'
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I ended up implementing the answer below but I really appreciated your speed and breadth of answers!